# How can I pass Dictionary<string, dynamic> to a blazor component?

Tags: dynamic, types, casting, blazor

I am trying to pass a dictionary as a parameter to a blazor component. The dictionary needs to store <string, dynamic>, <string, List>, and <string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> key-value pairs.

I tried to do this, but get the error, "'EventCallbackFactory' has no applicable method named 'CreateBinder' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched."

Is what I am trying to do valid, and if not, why? Is there another way I should approach this?

Here is the code for my blazor component, for reference:

```
@page "/dictitemcomponent"
@using System.Collections.Generic;

<ul>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in thisDict)
    {
        
        @if(item.Value.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, dynamic>))
        {
            <li>@item.Key.ToString() : </li>
            @foreach (var dict in item.Value)
            {
                <DictItemComponent thisDict=dict/>
            }
        }
        
        @if(item.Value.GetType() == typeof(List<dynamic>))
        {
            <li>@item.Key.ToString() : </li>
            @foreach (var value in item.Value)
            {
                <li>@value</li>
            }
        }
        
        @if(item.Value.GetType() != typeof(List<dynamic>) && item.Value.GetType() != typeof(Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>))
        {
            <li>@item.Key.ToString() : <input @bind="item.Value"/></li>       
        }
    }
</ul>

@code
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> newProperty = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>();
    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string,dynamic> thisDict {get; set;}= new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    //convert the value of a KVP to a dictionary
    public void ValueToProperty(KeyValuePair<string,dynamic> property)
    {
        string key = property.Key;
        property = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(key, new Dictionary<string, dynamic>());
    }

    public void ValueToList(KeyValuePair<string,dynamic> property)
    {
        string key = property.Key;
        property = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(key, new List<dynamic>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I know what you are trying to achieve?
Based on your first if statement, why would you have a dictionary inside a dictionary?
By reading your exception and your 3rd conditional statement, it seems that you are trying to bind the input to your dictionary value. However, this is not how you should use a dictionary. Unless you are binding to the usual "type" property (e.g. string), you may use `@bind=someVariable`. Otherwise, in a dictionary, each value should tie to their respective key and therefore, `@bind=_dict[key]` ("shorthand" syntax for `@bind-value` and `@bind-value:event`) instead of binding input to the `item.value`. For easier understanding, I've scoped out the aforementioned conditional statement and simulated a solution to the problem in the following lines. It should render value in the `<label>` next to the `input` during `onchange`:

```cs
    @page "/dict"
    @foreach (var kvp in _dict)
    {
    <div>
        <label>@kvp.Key</label>
        <input @bind=_dict[kvp.Key] />
        <label>Key:@kvp.Key|Value:@kvp.Value</label>
    }
    @code {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new()
        {
            ["1"] = "One",
            ["2"] = "Two",
            ["3"] = "Three",
            ["4"] = "Four",
            ["5"] = "Five",
        };
    }
    
    Meanwhile, you should simplify your if statements as follow:
    
    @if(item.Value.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, dynamic>))
    {
        //dowork
    }
    else if(item.Value.GetType() == typeof(List<dynamic>))
    {
        //do more work
    }
    else
    {
        //do other work
    }
```

[Screenshot for my Input fields rendered based on Key Value Pair and value entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG6Mr.png)